# How to use initial argument inside itertools.accumulate?

Tags: python, python-itertools, accumulate

In this [documentation link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) we can read this:

```
itertools.accumulate(iterable[, func, *, initial=None])
```

> Usually, the number of elements output matches the input iterable.
> However, if the keyword argument ***initial*** is provided, the accumulation
> leads off with the initial value so that the output has one more
> element than the input iterable.

However, I can not figure out how to use the `initial` argument.

If I use it like this:

```
accumulate([0, 7, 19, 13], operator.add,1)
```

I get error "TypeError: accumulate() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)".

I am using Python 3.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the function signature, you notice the "*". This means anything after it should be provided as keyword arguments. So your call should be:

```
accumulate([0,7,19,13], operator.add, initial=1)
```

but you said you're using Python 3.4, then you will not have the `initial` argument as it is only provided in Python 3.8, as per the documentation.